# Tkinter and PIL not loading jpegs

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to allow my Tkinter program to load and display .jpgs files from the standard .gif

```
import Image,ImageTk
root = Tk()
PILFile = Image.open("Image.jpg")
Image = PhotoImage(file=PILFile)
ImageLabel = Label(root,image=Image)
ImageLabel.image = Image
ImageLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The error message I get follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paragon/Programs/Python/Web/MP3Tagger.py", line 25, in <module>
albumart = PhotoImage(file=PILfile)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3271, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3227, in __init__
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
 _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "<JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1500x1500 at 0x98AEFCC>": no such file or directory
 [Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

I am absouletly certain that the file exists in the correct format,what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: @falsetru I don't think Tkinter Labels natively support `JPG` images.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND, Label is not a problem.  The code is using ImageTk, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [The Tkinter PhotoImage Class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm):

> The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files:
>
> ....
>   If you need to work with other file formats, the Python Imaging Library (PIL) contains classes that lets you load images in over 30 formats, and convert them to Tkinter-compatible image objects:
>
> ```
> from PIL import Image, ImageTk
>
> image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
> photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
> ```

-> Replace `Tkinter.PhotoImage` with `ImageTk.PhotoImage`:

```
root = Tk()
PILFile = Image.open("Image.jpg")
Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PILFile) # <---
ImageLabel = Label(root, image=Image)
ImageLabel.image = Image
ImageLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error occurs because of the argument `file`:

```
Image = PhotoImage(file=PILFile)
```

This would specify a file path. In addition, you want `ImageTk.PhotoImage`. Instead, you want:

```
Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PILFile)
```